# How to store users from another site in a list - PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, people-picker

I'd like to make a report of all sites in all of my web applications, and store site owners in one of columns. I am using PowerShell.

I can retrieve the owners using $Root.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Users
The problem is that when I try to create a SPUserValue object, to store it the People and Groups column, it requires a user ID, which is relative to the site.

Is it possible to store user information from different sites, or even web applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into using `SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName)` ([documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser?view=sharepoint-server), although it's not super informative on its own).

That method will create a *new* `SPUser` object for the site where you are trying to save all those values to your custom list, if it *does not* exist already, or return the *existing* `SPUser` object if it *does* already exist on that site.

That way you can get the user ID values that are specific to that site in order to make your `SPUserValue` objects.

Technically you will be "adding" all those users to the site where you are trying to collect the reporting information, but IIRC using `EnsureUser` does *not* grant those users any permissions, it just adds them to the `SiteUsers` collection.

Comment: Thank you!
Works perfectly and solved a problem I struggled with for quire some time now